# adding rows to html table with jquery and exporting html table to excel file with asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a html table which table, this html table have 1 row on page load,here is html table code:

```
<table class="datagrid" id="tablo1" runat="server" >
    <thead><tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>surname</th>
        <th >number</th>
           </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>ebrar</td>
            <td>bayburt</td>
            <td>999</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I can adding dynamically rows on run time with jquery,I using that code to adding rows to html table:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#ekle').click(function () {//tabloya veri ekleme
               $('#tablo1 > tbody:last')
               .append('<tr><td class="A">' +
               $('#name_').val()
               + '</td><td class="K">' +
               $('#surname_').val()
               + '</td><td class="A">' +
               $('#number_').val()
               + '</td></tr>');
            });
         });
    </script>
```

I can adding few rows to html table (the row values are coming from textboxes) and I can see the added rows in html table on runtime on a browser. After I will export my html table to a excle file,and I'm using that asp.net code :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=myexcel.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            tablo1.RenderControl(hw);
            Response.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.End();
        }
```

when I click 'ekle' button a file downloading which is an excel file.And I'm opening that file,I'm seeing only one row in excel file which row is the first row I added manualy in code it's that:

```
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>ebrar</td>
                <td>bayburt</td>
                <td>999</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

So I can't see in excel file the added rows with jquery which are seeing on table in browser .what can I do

Comment: just because these rows are added only in html rendered table on browser client side. there is no row created on server side.

Comment: Ok. How can I add rows realy

Comment: you can use server side code to add those rows to server control html table . as you already made that runat="server"

Comment: where must I write runat="server"

Comment: you already written that runat="server" . you have to replace your jquery code with c# code on page_load method .