# adding rows to html table from client and exporting html table to excel on client machine(browser)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

```
<table summary="merhaba" class="datagrid" id="tablo1" runat="server">
        <thead><tr>
            <th id="Th1" style="border:solid 1px #000000" runat="server">ad</th>
            <th id="Th2" runat="server">Soyad</th>
            <th id="Th3" runat="server">TC</th>
               </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>ebrar</td>
                <td>bayburt</td>
                <td>999</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I can adding rows with :

```
$('#button').click(function () {//tabloya veri ekleme
             $('#tablo1 > tbody:last')
               .append('<tr><td class="A">' +
               $('#ad_').val()
               + '</td><td class="K">' +
               $('#soyad_').val()
               + '</td><td class="A">' +
               $('#tc_').val()
               + '</td></tr>');

});
```

And I can exporting table to excel with this code:

```
protected void Button1_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=myexcel.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            tablo1.RenderControl(hw);
            Response.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.End();
         }
```

But when open the excel file I can't see the added rows which added from client,I can see only that row whic I added in code :

```
<tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>ebrar</td>
                <td>bayburt</td>
                <td>999</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

I had asked this question on

[my first question for exporting html table to excell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920633/adding-rows-to-html-table-with-jquery-and-exporting-html-table-to-excel-file-wit)

but I must adding rows with jquery, after adding I must exporting html table to excell with full of added rows ,is there any way ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because your c# code is backend and doesn't know you have manipulated the DOM. You would need to create your excel file in jQuery rather than c#.

This might help you.
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-create-excel-file-from-table-data